Trying to deploy Phaser-game to Github Pages, getting error: Blocked because of a disallowed MIME type
Here is the live site: https://topi1.github.io/phaser-game/
Here is the code: https://github.com/Topi1/phaser-game
Trying to deploy my first phaser game to GitHub Pages, but I get errors:
Loading module from “https://topi1.github.io/main.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
phaser-game
Loading failed for the module with source “https://topi1.github.io/main.js”.
I dont't really understand what am I supposed to do differently. Any help appreciated.
index.html currently looks like:
`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Game</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.80.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p>Demo</p>
    </header>
    <main>
      <canvas id="gameCanvas">
    
      </canvas>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Created by Topi 2024
    </footer>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
`

I have tried to move main.js around and in index.html I've tried to both variations of src="main.js" and src="/main.js". I also tried changing script type from module but did not work.

Use the relative src
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>

instead of
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>

– /main.js refers to https://topi1.github.io/main.js (as you noticed), but your project is in the /phaser-game/ subdirectory.

Thanks. I think that did something. That error is now gone. Now I got this: Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “phaser” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. main.js:2:20.

Its this line: import Phaser from 'phaser'. I tried changing "phaser" to "/node_modules/phaser" and to other variations but doesn't work.

Right – you're apparently not using a bundler, so you'll either need a bundler, or an import map so a browser knows where to get phaser from. Changing to node_modules won't work, because there is no node_modules in your repository (and there shouldn't be). You can use e.g. generator.jspm.io to generate an import map (or read their documentation to be able to do this locally).
